# Running maven with static analysis tools plugin like pmd, jdepend, findbugs ... Getting the below error !! Kindly help to resolve

Tags: maven, findbugs, pmd

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error getting reports from the plugin 'org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-1': Unable to load the mojo 'org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-1:findbugs' in the plugin 'org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin'. A required class is missing: edu/umd/cs/findbugs/AbstractBugReporter
```

Comment: Try to explicitly specify version of plugin. Use latest - 2.4.0.

Comment: Yup, try 2.40 as Andrew Logvinov mentions.  I have findbugs working on one my projects.  If you can post some sections of your pom.xml in regards to findbugs configurations, we may be able to get further.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is you simply using an outdated version of the [maven-findbugs-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/). The current version for the findbugs-plugin is 2.3.X or 2.4.0...That is causing the problems with missing classes etc.